# getting "org.openqa.selenium.json.jsonexception: unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characgters read: <" sometimes running by remotewebdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

Im my automation scripts while i am running using remotewebdriver in selenium grid it is throwing the errror as "org.openqa.selenium.json.jsonexception: unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characgters read: <" for few scenarios which ran totatlly fine in local using chromedriver.

Fialures are only when using remotewebdriver, can someone please help me in resolving this error

after checking few posts online, i tried to keep the platformname and version in the desired capabilities, still it didn't work